# Polymorphism C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'd like my code to print:

```
B B
A B
B A
```

But it prints

```
Item Item
Item Item
Item Item
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Item {
    Item(){}
    virtual void method1 (Item x, Item y) {cout << "Item Item\n";}
};

struct A : public Item {
    A(){}
};

struct B : public Item {
    B(){}
    virtual void method1 (B x, B y) {cout << "B B\n";}
    virtual void method1 (A x, B y) {cout << "A B\n";}
    virtual void method1 (B x, A y) {cout << "B A\n";}
};

int main ( void ) {
    Item * a[2];
    a[0] = new B; a[1] = new A;
    a[0]->method1(*a[0], *a[0]);
    a[0]->method1(*a[1], *a[0]);
    a[0]->method1(*a[0], *a[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your overloads of `method1` in `B` don't override the virtual method in `Item`.  So, when you call `someItem->method1`, it is not going to use them.

It looks like you want what is called "multiple dispatch", which C++ doesn't support directly.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#C.2B.2B for some discussion and workarounds.

Answer (score 5):

You are not overidding the `method1` with appropriate parameters so it keeps calling `method1` in `Item` class.

```
Item * a[2];
```

So `*a[0]` & `*a[1]` both are of the type `Item`. This causes your calls of:

```
a[0]->method1(*a[0], *a[0]);
a[0]->method1(*a[1], *a[0]);
a[0]->method1(*a[0], *a[1]);
```

as calls to `method1(Type,Type)` which is defined in the Base `Item` class.
You should override this method with `same parameters` in your child classes to be able to call methods in child class.

Here is what I think you are trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Item {
    Item(){}
    virtual void method1 (Item x, Item y) {cout << "Item Item\n";}
    virtual void method2 (Item x, Item y) {cout << "Item Item\n";}
    virtual void method3 (Item x, Item y) {cout << "Item Item\n";}
};

struct A : public Item {
    A(){}
};

struct B : public Item {
    B(){}
    virtual void method1 (Item x, Item y) {cout << "B B\n";}
    virtual void method2 (Item x, Item y) {cout << "A B\n";}
    virtual void method3 (Item x, Item y) {cout << "B A\n";}

};

int main ( void ) 
{
    Item * a[2];
    a[0] = new B; a[1] = new A;
    a[0]->method1(*a[0], *a[0]);
    a[0]->method2(*a[1], *a[0]);
    a[0]->method3(*a[0], *a[1]);
}
```

This will give you the desired output of:

```
output:
B B
A B
B A
```

Here method1()`,`method2()`&`method3()` are appropriately overridden in the Child class and hence they get called when called through a pointer actually pointing to a child class object.

Answer (score 4):

The type of `a` is an array of pointers to Item. The compiler must decide which method to call at compile time, not run time. Since all it knows is the types of the arguments, which is `Item`, that's the version that it calls.

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the signature of the function in the derived class. It's an entirely new virtual function now. You should not change the paramter type when you're deriving. It's only allowed to change the return type of a virtual function, that even should a derivation of the base class. Basically you're not really using runtime polymorphism in this case.

Comment: They both support polymorphism - `struct` and `class` in C++ differ in default access modifiers (`public` vs. `private`).

Answer (score 0):

The function that's called is based on the static type of the arguments, not the dynamic type.  So, they're all `Item`.  You're looking for a language feature called [multimethod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#C.2B.2B), which is not in C++ but can be emulated with some work.